# Getting red underline error trying to use automapper in a service layer .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm getting an error message trying to use automapper in my service layer.

I have a service class that's one layer deeper than the controller.
I tested the automapper code below and it works fine!

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<AddClaimDto, ARMDevelopment.injured>());
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
var dto = mapper.Map<ARMDevelopment.injured>(claimParams);
```

Now I want to setup the configuration in startup.cs like the automapper documentation suggests, so I did this below:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

and now I want to use it in my service file (which is called by the controller - actually two layers down).

```
var dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ARMDevelopment.injured>(claimParams);
```

But I see this with the error:

[image]

And the message says:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mapper.Map(object)'"

I understand that if it was the controller, I'd pass in the IMapper and set it in the controllers constructor, but I'm not in the controller.

Comment: I have not used Automapper through DI before, but it's very apparent that you should be injecting the Automapper object into your class, and using the instance rather than trying to use a non-static method as if it were static.

Comment: AutoMapper changed their API, not you cant use global static AutoMapper instance, you need to inject IMapper, and use that instance to map entity.

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using? [Starting with 9.0, the static API is no longer available.](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Setup.html)

Comment: So I can pass it through starting at my controller, where I see it being done that way in the documentation, but then I'm passing it down like 2 layers (objects) is that good or is there a better way?

Comment: @user1186050 That's the correct way. Any object that needs to do mapping should inject an instance of `IMapper` and [allow the DI container to handle resolving it](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core)

Comment: So I have my controller with a method called Add(params) and in it I call my repo like this var claim = await _repo.AddClaim(addClaimDto); where AddClaim() is a method from the interface. Would I pass IMapper in as a method parameter??

Comment: @user1186050 You _could_ use method injection in that scenario. However, constructor injection is usually a better approach (e.g. inject `IMapper` into the constructor of your repository)

Comment: It all depends on how you are creating the service class object within your controller. If it is injected by the DI through constructor then you can simply inject IMapper into your service class, then it will be injected by the framework itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the configuration in startup.cs for your service class too and inject the service class in controller before use. In that case you can inject the IMapper class in Service constructor and use it.

Say you Service class is TestService with interface ITestService.

Configuring on startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
```

In Controller

```
private readonly ITestService _service;
public class TestController(ITestService service){
     _service = service;
}
```

In Service

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
public class TestService(IMapper mapper){
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public void MyFunction() {
   var dto = _mapper.Map<ARMDevelopment.injured>(claimParams);
}
```

This should work!.